# How to find three consecutive rows with the for a given Id from a collection with some of the attributes same ? Java Stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, grouping

I have a scenario where I am reading from a csv file and loading into a List collection. The items are as below.

```
index    name    val1    val2     state    note
1         xxx     12.43    13.56    1       1
2         xxx     12.43    13.56    0       0 
3         xxx     12.43    13.56    0       0
4         yyy      5.9     13       1       1
5         zzz      5.4      5       0       1
6         ddd      6.8      7.78    1       1
7         ddd      6        1       1       0
8         xxx     12.43    13.56    1       1
9         zzz      1        1.56    1       1
10        ppp      1        0       0       0
11        yyy      1        1       1       0
12        ggg      1        1       1       1
13        ddd      1        1       0       0
14        www      0        0       0       0
15        www      1        0       0       0
```

Question 1 : I am trying to find three consecutive entries for a **given item-name** where the details of val1 and val2 haven't changed. If the values of these two fields haven't changed where they are non consecutive then it will still be fine (still count as consecutive).

How can i do using stream and get the number of consecutive entries with these three values ( name, val1 and val2) remaining same ?

Question 2: How can get a similar count for items which dont have three consecutive entries using stream for a given name?

I have tried doing something like this so far..

```
Map<String,Map<String,Map<String,Long>>> counting =  list.stream()
        .filter(p -> p.getName().equals(name))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getName,
                    Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getVal1, 
                            Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getVal2, Collectors.counting()))));
```

Edit : streams or no streams how can I do this ?

Comment: Don’t use streams for this. They are unsuited.

Comment: *Haven’t changed*: Would a change from 13.56 to 13.57 be enough that you consider the value changed, or have you got a (positive) tolerance?

Comment: @OleV.V. = There is no tolerance in the change as they all need to exactly same.

Comment: Could you exeplain what did you mean by - *If the values of these two fields haven't changed where they are non consecutive then it will still be fine (still count as consecutive).*? `groupingBy(item -> Arrays.asList(item.name,item.val1,item.val2)` might just be a direction, but consecutive part is not really clear.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase "three consecutive entries" indicated that it is unlikely that a straight stream solution is appropriate: streams are designed for operations on independent items.

Given you are only looking at items with the same name the first step is to group by name. You can use streams to do this with something like: `list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getName))`.

The for each list of items (i.e. the values in the generated map), you can use logic like the following:

```
int currentRun = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
    if (valuesMatch(list.get(i), list.get(i - 1))
        currentRun++;
    else
        currentRun = 0;
    if (currentRun > 3)
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code snippet will give a Map of the Items for a given item name whose val1 and val2 are equal. And the map will be grouped by val1 (or val2, doesn't matter as val1 and val2 will be same). And for your second issue, you can just append an '!' before p.getName().equals(name), like `!p.getName().equals(name)` . You have to check the size of the list of the items against the key though.

```
Map<Long, List<Item>> itemsMap = list.stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getName().equals(name) && p.getVal1().longValue()==p.getVal2().longValue())
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getVal1));
```